# Access SocketIO from another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to emit to all the sockets connected from a seperate file. However I cannot seem to figure it out.

**Socket.js**

```
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var users = require('./modules/users');

var io = socketio();
socket.io = io;

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  //Stuff
  console.log('Hello :)');
});

module.exports = socket;
```

**Users.js**

```
var socket = require('../socket');

function news(){
    socket.io.sockets.emit('news', {
        message: 'Woah! Thats new :)'
    })
}

setInterval(function(){
    news();
}, 5 * 1000);
```

However, `socket` in users.js seems to be empty and I can't seem to access to io object. How can I make it so I can emit to all users? Without parsing the io.sockets to the news function or moving my function to the socket file?

Comment: @JackBashford I'm pretty sure it doesn't matter for whether you add the `.js` or not, I like doing it like this as it looks clean.

Answer (score 13):

You can define io object with let as global variable in utils and io functions there. You can call these functions from any file. For example:

```js
// app.js

const { socketConnection } = require('./utils/socket-io');
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
socketConnection(server);
```

```js
// utils/socket-io

let io;
exports.socketConnection = (server) => {
  io = require('socket.io')(server);
  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.info(`Client connected [id=${socket.id}]`);
    socket.join(socket.request._query.id);
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.info(`Client disconnected [id=${socket.id}]`);
    });
  });
};

exports.sendMessage = (roomId, key, message) => io.to(roomId).emit(key, message);

exports.getRooms = () => io.sockets.adapter.rooms;
```

```js
// any file

const { sendMessage } = require('../utils/socket-io');

const foo = async () => {
  const roomId = '12345';
  const key = 'new-order';
  const message = 'new order assigned';
  
  sendMessage(roomId, key, message);
};
```

Comment: @grammerPro in `app.js` after `const server = http.createServer(app);` you need to start the server, here with port number 3001: `server.listen(3001);`

Answer (score 4):

Just create a `socket service` object, the service object only published some `helper` functions.

Example for your case:

```
// Socket.js
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var users = require('./modules/users');

var io = socketio();
socket.io = io;

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  //Stuff
  console.log('Hello :)');
});

var toAll = function (eventName, data) {
  io.sockets.emit(event, data);
}

module.exports = {
  toAll: toAll // publish `toAll` function to call every where
};


// Users.js
var socketService = require('../socket');

function news() {
  socketService.toAll('news', {
    message: 'Woah! Thats new :)'
  });
}

setInterval(function () {
  news();
}, 5 * 1000);
```

Comment: When I run my app with `npm start` it stops working and `socket` is empty, it only works when I run `users.js` seperately..

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer from [Furkan Uyar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9586025/furkan-uyar), I created a Typescript service

```js
// utils/socket-io.service.ts

import {Server, ServerOptions} from "socket.io";
import {Server as HttpServer} from "http";

export class SocketIOService {
  private static _instance: SocketIOService | undefined;
  private static server: Server | undefined;

  private constructor() {
    // Private constructor ensures singleton instance
  }

  static instance(): SocketIOService {
    if (!this._instance) {
      return new SocketIOService();
    }

    return this._instance;
  }

  initialize(httpServer: HttpServer, opts?: Partial<ServerOptions>) {
    SocketIOService.server = new Server(httpServer, opts);

    return SocketIOService.server;
  }

  ready() {
    return SocketIOService.server !== null;
  }

  getServer(): Server {
    if (!SocketIOService.server) {
      throw new Error('IO server requested before initialization');
    }

    return SocketIOService.server;
  }

  sendMessage(roomId: string | string[], key: string, message: string) {
    this.getServer().to(roomId).emit(key, message)
  }

  emitAll(key: string, message: string) {
    this.getServer().emit(key, message)
  }

  getRooms() {
    return this.getServer().sockets.adapter.rooms;
  }
}
```

The service must be initialized before use:

```js
// app.ts
import express from "express";
import log from "./logger";
import cors from "cors";
import {createServer} from "http";
import {SocketIOService} from "./utils/socket-io.service";


const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);

SocketIOService.instance().initialize(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: ['http://localhost:4200']
  }
});

const io = SocketIOService.instance().getServer();

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  log.info('a user connected');

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    log.info('user disconnected');
  });

  socket.on('my message', (msg) => {
    console.log('message: ' + msg);

    io.emit('my broadcast', `server: ${msg}`);
  });

  socket.on('room_update', (msg) => {
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  })
});

// ...
```

And then to call the service from another file (e.g. a HTTP Handler)

```js
import {SocketIOService} from "../utils/socket-io.service";
import log from "../logger";

function notifyUpdatedRoom(roomId: string) {
  log.info(`Notifying on updated room: ${roomId}`);

  if (roomId && SocketIOService.instance().ready()) {
    SocketIOService.instance().emitAll('room_update', roomId);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I managed to solve this by changing the position from the `module.exports`. I immediately put it after I initialized the `socket` variable, as it's the only thing I'm exporting it works.